# bash arguments in a variable and then loop through

Tags: macos, bash

I want DIR to loop through all the arguments (with space and "").  But this code do not recognize, "cd ef" as one. Dividing them into two. 
How can I do that?

```
#test.sh
echo Number of arguments: $#

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "No arguments"
  DIR=.
else 
  DIR="$*"
fi

echo DIR =$DIR
for arg in $DIR;
do 
  echo $arg;
done
```

Command

```
#bash test.sh ab "cd ef"
```

Output, Number of arguments: 2

But, enumerating 3 elements in the loop as `ab, cd`, and `ef`.

I know, I can do,

```
for arg in "$*";
```

But that not the solution in this case. Can I use DIR for this purpose?
The platform is OSX Mavericks shell.

Comment: `$*` is almost never appropriate for use -- it concatenates arguments with the first character of `IFS`, meaning that if any argument happens to _contain_ the first character of IFS, it's impossible to distinguish between the characters delimiting the arguments and the characters *within* the arguments.

Comment: Also, non-exported, non-builtin variables should have at least one lower-case variable to avoid potential namespace conflicts with environment variables and builtins.

Comment: BashFAQ #50, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 is (tangentially) relevant, inasmuch as it addresses many of the same misunderstandings that result in using scalar variables where they aren't appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an *array*, not a regular scalar variable, for this purpose -- and `"$@"`, not `$*`:

```
if (( $# )); then
  dirs=( "$@" )
else
  dirs=( . )
fi

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  ...
done
```

See also [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need a variable `DIR`, you can use a form of parameter expansion:

```
echo "DIR=${@:-.}"
for dir in "${@:-.}"; do
   ...
done
```